# Как сделать так чтобы html элемент созданный с помощью js не исчезал после перезагрузки страницы, без jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

```
function dayn() {
  io = document.querySelector('#production_conteiner');
  io.innerHTML += '<div class="imd_' + clas + '" onclick="addNum(this)"><a href="#popap_2" class="wew"><p class="p" id="p' + clas + '"></p><figure id="vyu"><img src="" class="myImg' + clas + '"><figcaption class="figcaption_1" id="figcaption_1' + clas + '"></figcaption><figcaption class="figcaption_2" id="figcaption_2' + clas + '"></figcaption></figure></a></div>';
  // div.onclick = dayns();
  rtg = "imd_" + clas;
  div = document.getElementsByClassName(rtg);
  // io.insertBefore(div, io.firstChild);
  let popip = document.querySelector(".textarea").value;
  rerir = document.querySelector("#p" + clas).innerHTML = popip;
  pop = document.getElementById("popop").value;
  rer = document.querySelector("#figcaption_1" + clas).innerHTML = pop;
  let popop = document.getElementById("pop").value;
  rerer = document.querySelector("#figcaption_2" + clas).innerHTML = popop;
  document.querySelector(".myImg" + clas).src = 'товар/' + txt;
  clas++;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: сессии или куки или localStorage/sessionStorage

Comment: Должен вас разочаровать: в данном случае js - это не то, что вам нужно. Js предназначен для работы с DOM элементами, которые обновляются при каждой перезагрузке. Можно использовать куки или подобные инструменты, однако это костыли, а для нормальной работы вашей задумки необходимо реализовать бэкенд.

Comment: с localStorege можно же взаимодействовать с помощью js, можете сказать что мне надобно написать в своём коде?

Comment: я сейчас практикуюсь делать интернет-магазин и у меня при перезагрузке страницы созданные карточки товара исчезают